# Which solution for nested routes and form_for?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, resources, routes, nested, form-for

In my Rails project with the objective to short the urls of my resources I created the route in routes.rb:

```
resources :users do
    resources :datas, controller: :data_defaults
end
```

And so I get the named paths: rake routes

```
user_datas     GET    /users/:user_id/datas(.:format)          data_defaults#index
               POST   /users/:user_id/datas(.:format)          data_defaults#create
 new_user_data GET    /users/:user_id/datas/new(.:format)      data_defaults#new
edit_user_data GET    /users/:user_id/datas/:id/edit(.:format) data_defaults#edit
     user_data GET    /users/:user_id/datas/:id(.:format)      data_defaults#show
               PUT    /users/:user_id/datas/:id(.:format)      data_defaults#update
               DELETE /users/:user_id/datas/:id(.:format)      data_defaults#destroy
```

Then I use the partial _form.html.haml to create the new and edit a data_default record.
In the DataDefault controller i have for the new and edit action:

```
def new
  @data_default = current_user.data_defaults.new
  ...
end
def edit
  @data_default = DataDefault.find(params[:id])
end
```

Then in the _form partial i have for the action form:

```
=form_for [current_user,@data_default] do 
.....
```

At this point when I start to get a new or edit a DataDefault record I get the error:

```
undefined method `user_data_defaults_path'
```

But I know to have changed the route for the controller, so I add the url: to the `form_for`
But I need to explicitally define different url for different action new or edit as:

```
- uurl = action_name == "new" ? user_datas_path(current_user, @data_default) : user_data_path(current_user, @data_default)
= form_for [current_user,@data_default] do |f|
```

NOTE: The user_datas_path and the user_data_path for different actions.

The question is: with this kind of routes, is that the correct way to have a working form?
Thank's to all.
Giorgio

Answer (score 1):

You should define resources based on model's name because Rails guesses route name based on objects in form_for, or you can specify the url manaully.

route:

```
resources :users do
    resources :data_defaults
end
```

If you want that the url is looked like `/users/:user_id/datas(.:format)`, you can:

```
resources :users do
    resources :data_defaults, path: 'datas'
end
```

view:

```
=form_for [current_user,@data_default] do |f|
  = f.text_field :name .............

=link_to 'back', users_data_defaults_path(current_user)
```